# Get current user in Passport.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, yeoman-generator-angular

I have following Express.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var compression = require('compression');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler');
var path = require('path');
var config = require('./environment');
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports = function(app) {
    var env = app.get('env');

    app.set('views', config.root + '/server/views');
    app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.use(compression());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(methodOverride());
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session()); // passport session middleware 
    if ('production' === env) {
        app.use(favicon(path.join(config.root, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
        app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'public')));
        app.set('appPath', config.root + '/public');
        app.use(morgan('dev'));
    }

    if ('development' === env || 'test' === env) {
        app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
        app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, '.tmp')));
        app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'client')));
        app.set('appPath', 'client');
        app.use(morgan('dev'));
        app.use(errorHandler()); // Error handler - has to be last
    }
};
```

After the user has logged in using Facebook, in my controller when I try to do 
`req.user` or `req.session.passport.user` is get `undefined`.

How can I get the current logged in user?

Comment: This isn't sufficient code.

Comment: Please add `passport.serializeUser`, `passport.deserializeUser`, and `passport.use()` calls. Also, if the above is your full Express app configuration you do not have session support. Install [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) and take in use **before** calling `passport.session()`

Answer (score 13):

When an authentication succeeds **req.user** is automatically set to the user

```
var express               = require("express"),
app                   = express(),
bodyParser            = require("body-parser"),
mongoose               = require("mongoose"),
passport              = require("passport"),
flash                 = require("connect-flash"),
localStrategy         = require("passport-local"),
User                  = require("./models/user"),
passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose")


app.use(require("express-session")({
secret: "demoapp",
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.set("view engine", "ejs")
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/dashboard"));
```

**Get the current user details. You can set the currentUser to your own 
    text**

```
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  next();
})
```

**if you are using ejs show the user profile in the browser**

```
<p> <%= currentUser.username %> </p>
<p> <%= currentUser.country %> </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define authentication strategies and call passport.authenticate to authenticate your users.
See an example in [the passport guide](http://passportjs.org/guide/)

Comment: i am able to authenticate and login . When i goto homepage and it makes bunch of call to get data and store some info. To store info i need user information.

Comment: @harshit - did you post the full code? Have you implemented the passport serialization function?

Comment: yes i missed adding passport serialization function .